# command with subprocess.call() to run virtualenv doesn't work

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm trying to run my virtualenv called env (created before) using call() from subprocess and it doesn't work. Command is fine, it's working when I type it directly in terminal.

python code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("source env/bin/activate", shell=True)
```

I was trying also:

```
import os
os.system("source env/bin/activate")
```

any ideas why command is not performed or what should I use instead os.system() and subprocess.call()?

Answer (score 1):

In both examples, your code launches a subprocess.  That subprocess, which has its own environment, attempts to run the "source" command, and then exits.  Since the subprocess has its own environment, this has no effect on the current process.

Assuming your end goal is to run some other command in the subprocess, you should just run it directly.  You don't specifically need to activate the virtual environment.

```
subprocess.call(["./env/bin/pip", "list"])
```

Avoid using the `shell=True` option if at all possible; it can be quite dangerous if you're not extremely careful with it.

If you really need to set the environment variables that the `activate` script sets in this script, you need to manually set them in `os.environ`.  You can read the `activate` script to see what they are.  They usually won't matter, though.